# как сравнить два введенных числа в input? js

Tags: javascript, сравнение

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="one">
            <input id="two">
            <button onclick="myFunction">Сравнить</button>
        </form>
        <p  id="demo">Ответ</p>
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            var a, b, c;
            a = document.getElementById("one").value;
            b = document.getElementById("two").value;
            c = (a > b) ? a:b;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c;   
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a, b, c;
  a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("one").value);
  b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("two").value);
  c = (a > b) ? a : b;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c;   
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="one">
  <input id="two">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Сравнить</button>
</form>
<p id="demo">Ответ</p>
```